# Specify xtics when the format is hh:mm

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot [here](http://91.121.173.204/plot.2016.05.18_PM.svg) and Gnuplot chose to space the xtics 2 hours apart. How can I specify 1 hour spacing of xtics? I can't seem to work it out from the documentation, nor find a matching example online.

I have tried:

```
set xtics "12:00" "13:00" "24:00"

set xtics 12:00 13:00 24:00

set xtics "12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00","24:00"

set xtics 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00, 19:00, 20:00, 21:00, 22:00, 23:00, 24:00
```

(with and without ' quote marks around the ranges)

Comment: `help xtics` should be helpful...this isn't the syntax of xtics. If problems persist give a sample of your datafile and your plot command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a time axis the basic units are seconds, so you must use a tic increment of 3600 :seconds

```
set xtics 3600
```

Comment: That works. Thank you! (My upvote will register when I have enough reputation).